# add RESTful action in sonata-admin

Tags: rest, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I added a new action (fooAction) in sonata admin bundle.
In list view there is an attribute which linked to newAction, but the its URL is like this : `admin\bundle\entity\foo?id=17` 
fooAction works correctly ,But I want the Url to be RESTful like this: `admin\bundle\entity\17\foo`
what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `configureRoutes` function,you must replace this :

```
$collection->add('foo');
```

to :

```
$collection->add('foo',$this->getRouterIdParameter() .'/foo');
```